# Excel 2007, VBA: Retail 6.5.1057 -- Application.OnTime

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2007

Windows 10 Pro
Version 21H2 OS build 19044.1586 Excel 2007,
VBA: Retail 6.5.1057 - Forms3: 12.0.6723.500

**THE ISSUE:**

Under normal usage, Application.OnTime (with a running timer), if and when Excel is manually closed --will remain closed prior to the scheduled time, Exel will reopen then run the scheduled procedure, and leave Excel open; without human interaction.

I'm unable to find an explanation as to why, when the machine reboots --post Win-10 update--, and Excel automatically reopens, the previously active timer will not run --or is otherwise cancelled, until the timer is manually run again.

Any known documentation explaining this? My queries keep resulting in the usage for Application.OnTime.

Respectfully.

Comment: Your statement about the behaviour under normal usage is incorrect. The schedule is maintained by Excel so, if you close **Excel**, the schedule is cleared and the workbook will not be reopened at the scheduled time. If you close just the workbook, then it will be reopened at the scheduled time.

Comment: Fully agree to Rory. `Application` is referring to the Excel Application itself and if this Application is closed, it cannot do anything - so likely you close a worksheet but not Excel itself (you can check this with the task manager).  When you reboot, then the Excel Instance is gone and the next time you start Excel, a new instance is created. --- If you want to execute a task at a certain time and you want that this information survives a reboot, use the Window Scheduler

Comment: Prior to this thread, I was interpreting 'closing the Workbook' as closing 'Excel' --given there is only one Workbook open. <-- By that I mean, left-clicking the upper-right corners' red 'X'. If I'm understanding these current replies properly,  if Excel-2007 is running, after a machine restart --even though Excel automagically reopens the Workbook that Windows update closed, Excel and the previously opened Workbook can resume, but any/all previously running timers are not resumed (cancelled), for that same reopened Workbook? I think I'm missing something.

Comment: Is anyone able to clarify the Workbook -vs- Excel, being open or closed, and how to know the difference?